# Tracking consumption and usage of a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have a JavaScript library that is served from an ASP.NET MVC site. I want to track the usage of this library. I am only interested in tracking the page the library is loaded into,  when it is loaded, and how many times it is loaded. I do not need to track other analytics.

Here are the ways I can think of to do this:

1. Embed analytics into the consuming web page after the JavaScript file is loaded. This is possible because my library injects HTML elements into the DOM of the consuming page. As far as privacy concerns go, this library is really just meant for internal usage for the organization I work for, so I probably don't have to worry too much about this. We use Google Analytics.
2. Setup an ASP.NET MVC controller that serves the JavaScript file out and track every request. I believe this is what Google does with Google Maps and some of its other libraries.

I was wondering if anybody had any general recommendations on how best to accomplish this. I've tried to get this setup with Google Analytics, but the page URLs in the GA reports don't display the full URL of the requesting page. It seems that GA assumes that the requests for a certain tracking code originate from the base domain.

Comment: I would think the controller method, or server logs, likely wouldn't track cached file requests.

Comment: Good point. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered making your JavaScript file create an image variable and track usage that way?

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.mysite.com/controller/action?t=' + new Date().getTime();
```

or

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.mysite.com/controller/action?url=' + escape(window.top.location) + '&t=' + new Date().getTime();
```

You wont have to write to the DOM but the image will get rendered behind the scenes. You can expand this by passing any other variables you want to collect.

Comment: I should have noted that the variable "t" is a timestamp which will prevent caching of the page. You could also create a custom route which uses the time stamp as part of the structure: www.mysite.com/images/{t}/1px.gif?u={url}

Comment: I like the simplicity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

at the end of library write codes to make an ajax request to the server with current url as parameter.

Eg: if you are using jQuery u can do as below.

**JS**

```
....
other codes
....
jQuery.ajax({
      url:'/home/Tracking_Url',
      type:'POST',
      data:{url:window.location+""}
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
public Tracking_Url(string url)
{
    //do something with url
}
```

Comment: Good answer too. I marked @Splash-X's as the answer because he responded first. Thanks!